# Switching Capybara drivers with environment variables

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am running Cucumber tests with Capybara and I want to be able to run sets of tests with different drivers like selenium or poltergeist. I've registered all my drivers and can switch between them with environment variables in the following fashion:

```
if ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER'] == ":poltergeist" do
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

My question is, is there some way to pass the driver in the environment variable without this use of if blocks?

Ideally, I'd like to do `Capybara.default_driver = ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER'] || :selenium` but this produces errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `to_sym` to convert the ENV variable into a symbol, then remove the colon from the variable. Right now you are using ":poltergeist", which is a string, instead of `:poltergeist`, which is a symbol.

`Capybara.default_driver = ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER'].to_sym` will work if `ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER']` is "poltergeist".

Comment: Keep in mind that if `ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER']` is nil, `to_sym` will raise a NoMethodError.

Comment: (ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER']&&ENV['DEFAULT_DRIVER'].to_sym) it is then.

Comment: If using Rails, you can also do `.try(:to_sym)` :)